# Getting UniqueID inside OnClientClick() to pass as a parameter to a JS function

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, webforms, devexpress

I am using a DevExpress grid and the DataItemTemplate for a column as follows:

```
<DataItemTemplate>
    <asp:Button Visible="True" EnableViewState="False" CssClass="btn btn-sm btn-danger" data-confirm="Are you sure you want to delete this Organisation Member?" ID="DeleteButton" data-id="<%#: Container.KeyValue %>" runat="server" Text="Delete" OnClientClick=' return DeleteConfirm("<%= UniqueID %>"); ' OnClick="DeleteButton_OnClick" />
</DataItemTemplate>
```

I want to pass the unique identifier for the button to my JS function DeleteConfirm() as a parameter.

However instead of the unique identifier I am getting the string **<%= UniqueID %>**

How get the unique identifier for each button passed a parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Item within the `<%= %>` or `<%# %>` notation cannot be references to properties on that object itself.  You should be able to pass `this` and then use the button directly though:

```
return DeleteConfirm(this);
```

The `this` reference would be the reference to the button.